# Pidgin consume any char until match and not consume second match

Tags: c#, parser-combinators

I try to parse various input strings to list of object and some of that input may contains punctuation marks.

I do not success until consume a string block or something else.

Test input strings correctly working:

```
var inputs = new List<string>{
    "prefix{{test='5'}}middle{{'test string'}}{{'test1'}}postfix",
    "{{test='5'}}middle{{'test string'}}{{'test1'}}postfix",
    "{{test='5'}}middle{{'test string'}}{{'test1'}}",
}
```

However that all contains letter and digit. So this one is not working:

```
var notWorkingInput= ".?n6y{{test='5'}}+*854d{{'test string'}}{{'test1'}}ret0}";
```

Expected result of `notWorkingInput` is in that order:

1. Text Object (`Name = ".?n6y"`)
2. Test2 Object (`Name = "test", Value="5"`)
3. Text Object (`Name = "+*854d"`)
4. Test1 Object (`Name = "test string"`)
5. Test1 Object (`Name = "test1"`)
6. Text Object (`Name = "ret0}"`)

I use [Pidgin](https://github.com/benjamin-hodgson/Pidgin) parsing library.

Full working code:

```
public class TestParser {
    private static readonly Parser<char, string> ObjectStart = String("{{");
    private static readonly Parser<char, string> ObjectEnd = String("}}");
    private static readonly Parser<char, string> Equal = String("=");

    private static Parser<char, T> Tok<T>(Parser<char, T> token) => Try(token).Before(SkipWhitespaces);
    private static Parser<char, string> Tok(string token) => Tok(String(token));

    private static readonly Parser<char, string> StringLiteralDouble = Tok(Try(String("\"\"")).ThenReturn('"')
            .Or(Token(c => c != '"'))
            .ManyString()
            .Between(Char('"')));

    private static readonly Parser<char, string> StringLiteralSingle = Tok(Try(String("''")).ThenReturn('\'')
            .Or(Token(c => c != '\''))
            .ManyString()
            .Between(Char('\'')));

    private static readonly Parser<char, string> StringLiteral = Tok(OneOf(StringLiteralDouble, StringLiteralSingle));

    private static readonly Parser<char, ITest> Test1Statement = Tok(StringLiteral.Between(Whitespaces).Between(ObjectStart, ObjectEnd))
        .Select<ITest>(s => new Test1(s));
    private static readonly Parser<char, ITest> Test2Statement = Tok(Letter.ManyString()).Before(Tok(Equal))
        .Then(OneOf(Num.Select<dynamic>(s => s), Real.Select<dynamic>(s => s), StringLiteral.Select<dynamic>(s => s), LetterOrDigit.ManyString().Select<dynamic>(s => s)), (s, v) => new Test2(s, v)).Between(ObjectStart, ObjectEnd)
        .Select<ITest>(s => s);

    private static readonly Parser<char, ITest> TextStatement = LetterOrDigit.AtLeastOnceString().Select<ITest>(s => new Text(s));


    private static readonly Parser<char, ITest> Statement = OneOf(Test1Statement, Test2Statement, TextStatement);
    private static readonly Parser<char, IEnumerable<ITest>> Statements = Statement.Many();

    public static Result<char, IEnumerable<ITest>> Parse(string input) => Statements.Parse(input);
}

public interface ITest {
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Test1 : ITest {
    public string Name { get; }
    public Test1(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Test2 : ITest {
    public string Name { get; }
    public dynamic Value { get; }
    public Test2(string name, dynamic value) {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class Text : ITest {
    public string Name { get; }

    public Text(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I test `AnyCharExcept('{', '}')`. Actually, it is working but single bracket problem now.

**UPDATE 2:**

If possible to add something like that `AnyExcept` also it will be good.

**UPDATE 3:**

Author of library [adviced me](https://github.com/benjamin-hodgson/Pidgin/issues/87#issuecomment-738873444) to use `Any.Until(Lookahead(String("{{")).Or(End))` but it is not working.

Comment: Is Pidgin some kind of library in this case? I'm only familiar with it as the IM client.

Comment: Yes, [Pidgin](https://github.com/benjamin-hodgson/Pidgin) is parsing library in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this custom parser which solves the problem for me:

```
internal class AnyStringExcept : Parser<char, string>
{
    private readonly string[] terminators;

    public AnyStringExcept(params string[] terminators)
    {
        this.terminators = terminators;
    }

    public override bool TryParse(ref ParseState<char> state, ref PooledList<Expected<char>> expecteds, out string result)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var found = false;
        while (state.HasCurrent && !found)
        {
            // unfortunately this cannot be simplified as
            // found = terminators.Any(terminator => terminator == state.LookAhead(terminator.Length).ToString());
            // because the ref parameter state cannot be used in a lambda expression

            foreach (var terminator in terminators)
            {
                var nextChars = state.LookAhead(terminator.Length).ToString();
                if (nextChars != terminator)
                    continue;

                found = true;
                break;
            }

            if (found)
                break;

            sb.Append(state.Current);
            state.Advance();
        }

        result = sb.ToString();
        return result != "";
    }
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
var RAW_TEXT = new AnyStringExcept("<ls:", "</ls:");
```

This uses Pidgin 3.2.1. Hope it helps.